# How to mount external SD card at a fixed path in CM13?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, sd-card

In Marshmallow (and consequently in CM13), the external SD card is mounted at a path that contains its serial number. I have a bunch of Tasker tasks, the occasional script, and lots and lots of apps configured with a specific path to the external SD card (in my case, /external_sd because that's where it was in CM12).

Is there anything sensible I can do about this change in Marshmallow? Fixing paths everywhere just because I've upgraded to a faster/larger SD card (which has a different serial number) is not going to be fun.

How would I go about making the external SD card available under "/external_sd" on CM13/Marshmallow?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a reasonably easy way to do something close enough: just set the volume serial number to something fixed. This is easy enough for FAT32-formatted SD cards: just use [Sysinternals VolumeID](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897436.aspx):

```
D:\>vol D:
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 07F5-432C

D:\>volumeid D: ECAD-ECAD

VolumeID V2.01 - Set disk volume id
Copyright (C) 1997-1999 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Volume ID for drive D: updated to ecad-ecad
```

("ecad" for "external card" but there are [other possibilities](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/HexWords.htm), of course)

Now my external SD card is mounted at `/storage/ECAD-ECAD`, which is easy to remember for typing in those apps which don't let me pick a path, and more importantly, can stay the same when I upgrade to a faster card, for example (if I repeat this procedure).

The only complication is SD cards larger than 32 GB, which Windows refuses to format into FAT32. The best tool to work around this is [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), an open-source tool with a focus on bootable drives, but it can also just format a large FAT32 drive.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a init.d script to re-create the sdcard link.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

SERIAL=`ls /mnt/media_rw/ | head -n 1`
FULL_PATH="/mnt/media_rw/$SERIAL"
SERIAL_LENGTH=${#SERIAL}
LINK_NAME="/external_sd"

if [ -e $LINK_NAME ] ; then
    echo "Link already exists!"
elif [[ $SERIAL_LENGTH -lt 1 ]] ; then
    echo "Badly formed path!"
elif [ ! -d "$FULL_PATH" ] ; then
    echo "SdCard path not found!"
else
    mount -o rw,remount /
    ln -s $FULL_PATH $LINK_NAME
    mount -o ro,remount /
fi
```

This script assumes:

- that init.d scripts aren't being blocked by SEAndroid,
- that your device needs to be turned off to change the sdcard, and
- that it only has space for one sdcard.

I assume the reason for the introduction of serial numbers in the sdcard path is for devices with space for more than one sdcard.