# How to rename an ext. SDCARD

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd

When running the stock Samsung firmware on my Galaxy Note 4 (N910C), the external SDCARD was mounted at **/storage/extSdCard**.
I have recently installed CM13 (Bliss-ROM) and the external SDCARD got mounted at **/storage/3937-3663** instead.

As a result, my restored apps (via TitaniumBackup) are looking at /storage/extSdCard for files that are actually at /storage/3937-3663.

What's the ideal way to resolve my "apps looking in the wrong place" problem? 
Renaming **"3937-3663"** to **"extSdCard"** is not possible. 
Telling the apps the correct path would be very time-consuming, esp. for apps like "Tasker", which has many wrong path-entries now due to above change of path.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Easiest way is probably shutting down your Note4, removing the card, mounting it to your PC using a card reader, and "label" it there. How the last step is done of course depends on the OS used. Linuxes usually have the `dosfslabel` command (part of the `dosfstools` package) or `mlabel`, on Windows you should be able to rename it by right-clicking the drive entry in Explorer and choosing "properties". That done, unmount it safely, put it back to your Note4, and switch on the latter. Should now appear at the assumed place again.

Comment: @Izzy he's not asking about renaming the memory card name (label). Till Lollipop 5.1, the memory card was symlinked (mount -bind) as /storage/sdcard1 or whatever. But since marshmallow, it appears as /storage/xxxx-xxxx, where the xxxx-xxxx is memory card unique id or something IDK. He's asking how to get it back like /storage/extSdCard as we had till Android 5.1 :)

Comment: @GokulNC to my experience, that ID (in exact the format given) is used as label if no label was explicitly set. I see the same on my Linux machines: SD cards appear in `/media/XXXX-XXXX` when new, but as soon as I label them they show up there as `/media/MyLabel`. This behavior exactly matches the description given by Parinibbana (simply replace `/storage` with `/media`), hence my comment. Doesn't hurt to try what I wrote above – so if OP does that and reports back, we will know.

Comment: @Izzy Okay, I just tried what you commented and rebooted, didn't work.. It's still the same :)

Comment: @GokulNC so you had a case exactly matching the above, where the card appears as `/storage/1234-5678` – and after labeling the card it turned up the very same? OK, good to know then. Glad my card still turns up at the very same place as before, not with its ID (Android 5.1.1 – which is why I mention it).

Comment: Thanks guys for chipping-in. 
I tried the renaming as suggested by GokulNC, but it didn´t work here either.

Comment: Ah. So Android differs from Linux here and uses the VolumeID regardless of whether a volume name was set. I can see the reasoning, though I would have made using the volume label at least an option. Thanks for the pointer, will follow your advice and close this as dupe then.

Comment: I just realized that a similar question was already asked here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142043/how-to-mount-external-sd-card-at-a-fixed-path-in-cm13

The answer given there is not a solution to the problem (if there even is a solution), but the question itself is similar. Thanks Izzy for pointing this out.